# SPA + API OAuth flow, what to use?

Tags: node.js, angular, express, authentication, oauth-2.0

We are struggling about what OAuth flow to use with our app.

We are using Node.JS as our back-end API and Angular as our front-end.

What we want to do is, log in an user, retrieve an access token and use this access token in order to make some API requests (basic POST/GET/PUT/DELETE).

- A user (still unknown at this point) lands on a login form OR a register form. He proceeds to the login or the registration.
- Once logged he's on his dashboard with an access token, now every time he wants to interact with the API he must use his access token in order to interoperate with the back-end. (which is a classical behavior).

This seems easy, we wanted to use the **Implicit Flow** but we need a *client_id* in order to retrieve an access token and the user is still unknown at this point.

We then thought about using the **Password Grant** flow because our users will have a login/password, but OAuth specs. recommend not to use it except we have no choice.

I know this is a super basic question but what kind of OAuth flow do you recommend with this ? If we have no choice we'll just use the **Password Grant** but wanted to explore every single solution.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand what you mean by:

> we wanted to use the Implicit Flow but we need a
>   client_id in order to retrieve an access token and the user is still
>   unknown at this point.

If you are using Oauth2.0s implicit flow then your angular app should be registered as a public client with the authorisation server - that process would give you a unique `client_id` for your angular app. Your angular app can then use the `implicit grant` and redirect the unknown user to the authorisation server's *authorise* endpoint passing along in the querystring its `client_id` along with its `redirect_uri` and various other things.

The *authorise* endpoint will prompt the user to register/login to the identity provider and *consent* to the *scopes* your Angular app requests.
 Once the user logs in (or registers), the authorisation server should then redirect back to your Angular app's registered `redirect_uri` passing an `access_token` in the hash-segment of the returned http querystring.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I know that I'm not answering directly to your question. 
But did you consider using an authentification backend as [Auth0](https://auth0.com/) ?

Security is key and OAuth is a complex protocol. 
Auth0 give you every thing you need to manage users, use a social identity provider, and integration with Angular.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! We did consider using Auth0 but things are that my company is a bit afraid of this. I might try to give them better arguments in order to use it actually !